# Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'+ Windows CE

Tags: .net, windows-ce

Hi We have created WCF service and consuming the same in Windows mobile 6.1 i.e with Net compact edition
We have successfully updated the service reference; But while calling the login method we are getting exception as "Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'"
We are getting exception with this.Invoke method; we have configured WCF with basichttp binding and its working well with other desktop application.

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct URL? - Try browsing to it from a browser.

Comment: Hi we are able to browse url on browser and able to see WSDL.